# android singleton activity

Tags: android, android-activity, singleton, android-intent

The main activity of the app is TabActivity that contains some OneActivity

It is necessary to call from another part of app the OneActivity not creating the another instance of it,
just calling onResume() of the one that lies in TabActivity

Tried set different launchMode ("singleTop", "singleTask", "singleInstance") and set flags for intent:

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

How to do it not creating a new instance of activity?

Comment: Pull the code you require to call into a static method. Then call it using OneActivity.yourMethod();

Answer (score 5):

Try the `CLEAR_TOP` flag. I removes all the activities above your activity in the activity stack, so it should solve your purpose.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, YourSingleInstanceActivityName.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thank you, I set as you adviced this flag for intent and the other one:

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
then I set launchMode "sinleTop" for SingleInstanceActivity

And when I set SingleInstanceActivity as the MAIN it works definetly as I need, but when I put it in a TabActivity and make this TabActivity MAIN, it starts to create new instances of SingleInstanceActivity again.