# How to avoid multiple instances of same Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my PoC, I have some Activities, `HomeActivity`, `CreateActivity`, `SearchActivity`, `ResultsActivity`, `ResultDetailsActivity`, and `UpdateActivity`.

I have two main navigation paths: **Create** and **Search**.

Navigation for the **Create** path is as follows: `HomeActivity`--> `CreateActivity` -(on complete)-> `HomeActivity`

Navigation for **Search** is as follows: `HomeActivity`--> `SearchActivity` --> `ResultsActivity`(`ListActivity`) --> `ResultDetailsActivity` --> `UpdateActivity` -(on complete)-> `ResultDetailsActivity` (with updated data).

Currently, navigation to a new `Activity` is via `startActivity(intent)` method. However, this is causing multiple instances of each `Activity` to be opened.

I'm rather new to Android. Could someone please suggest how I could avoid this?

Comment: You can try SingleTon Pattern for it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Setting either the following flags may help you to resolve your issue:

- `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`
- `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`

Comment: If I go with `Intent` flags, then, in my **Create** path, after creating a new dataset in `CreateActivity`, should I add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag to the code in my button to navigate to the `HomeActivity`? I've also overriden `onBackPressed` in `CreateActivity` with `this.finish()`.

Comment: I guess you should `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` because then it will clear all the front activities including **CreateActivity** and take you to first activity which should be **HomeActivity**

Answer (score 41):

In your android manifest, Add to your `<activity>` tag the `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

For a full list, check the [documentation of activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

In your manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Note: don't use singleton.

Comment: I've seen a [blog](http://intridea.com/posts/android-understanding-activity-launchmode) for `android:launchMode="singleTop"`, but unfortunately couldn't understand it very well. May I have a slightly more newbie-friendly source, please?

Comment: I was having issues with `singleInstance` as it affected navigation when going back from an activity opened on top (the prev activity was being killed when going to background). Fortunately `singlesTask` doesn't have that issue.

Answer (score 9):

Use `Intent` flag when `startActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

there are many kinds of flag.

This will be helpful:
[android singleton activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131352/android-singleton-activity)

Comment: if you want to prevent multiple instance in same Activity, then FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP will be nice

Answer (score 3):

The best form to manage the Activities is use

startActivityForRestult(Intent,ID)

With this method to call Activities your HomeActivity can manage a result for the other activities in the Override method

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

You can send known result for the diferents Activities and manage it. For example:
*(Allways with startActivityForResult)*

HomeActivity --> SearchActivity --> ResultsActivity(ListActivity) --> ResultDetailsActivity --> UpdateActivity -(on complete)-> ResultDetailsActivity (with updated data). Press Return and send  SEARCH_fINISHED -->UpdateActivity catch this and send the same result in the onActivityResult method and finish() --> The same with searchActivity --> Home

This can help you too:

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/

Answer (score 1):

Few things to add on to the answer posted by JoonSung Kim, change the addFlag method which will throw "cannot resolve error"

change: `intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);`

to: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);`

code should be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

To prevent multiple instance of a same Activity change the flag

from : `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);`

to: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

code should be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`
in onCreate(...) method of Activity.