# Same Activity is created twice if you open from another APP

Tags: android

If you have an APP open in Activity B and you use APP(2) to open the same Activity it will create another instance of Activity B and now you will have 2 Activities B.

Is there any way to make it open the Activity that is already open, instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614565/how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-of-same-activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes in your manifest use launchMode:singleTask in your activity tag

```
<activity

        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
         -------------- Your Activity---------
 <activity/>
```

Answer (score 1):

use  in your andorid manifest to make sure that only one instance of activity is created

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` for activity in `AndroidManifest`
And override `onNewIntent` in activity to get data when new `startActivity()` called

Answer (score 0):

Following [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html#IntentFlagsForTasks) you should add following flag into starting intent:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below flag before `startActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

And add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for activity tag in your manifest file.