# Activity open twice

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

in my application 3 pages are there

1-splash

2-login

3-OTPpage

In splash page same values are sending to login page using putextra method
but login page open twice so when add back button for `System.exit(0)` login page will open again,
so I add  `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in manifest, after adding this line transfer value is changing irregularly what should i do.. is there any other method to prevent repeat creating activity

activity starting code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // The first time mTimeBeforeDelay will be 0.
    long gapTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mTimeBeforeDelay;
    if (gapTime > SPLASH_SCREEN_MS) {
        gapTime = SPLASH_SCREEN_MS;
    }
    mSplashHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("first_time", true)) {
                if (isConnectingToInternet()) {
                    frstrequest();
                } else {
                    ViewDialog1 alert = new ViewDialog1();
                    alert.showDialog(Splash.this, "Make Sure Internet is Connected", R.drawable.no_internet);
                }


            } else {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ApplockActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
                Splash.this.finish();


            }
        }
    }, gapTime);
    // Save the time before the delay.
    mTimeBeforeDelay = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSplashHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```

manifest

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"


            android:screenOrientation="portrait">



        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
           android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: This is different thing, android:launchMode="singleTask" First you should put your code in the question that how you starting your Activity.

Comment: Post your code so that all can have a look.

Comment: share your manifest file

Answer (score 2):

If your activity is calling twice from anywhere then it would create its two instances and in result your activity will open twice you can stop it by launch modes please visit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958746/7230266)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19746116)

Comment: @Kos Seems fine to me.

Comment: @EJoshuaS this answer looks more like a comment to OP's post